# Karma auto-watch is not working

Tags: javascript, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I've used Karma about 1 year ago and everything worked fine. When I changed the tests and saved the .test.js file, the test auto-ran - didn't have to restart or change anything.
Today I wanted to run these tests again. Having a new computer, I had to install node and npm and whatnot, and then I installed also:

`npm install -g karma karma-cli karma-jasmine karma-chrome-launcher`

I configured Karma as follows (`karma init`):

```
    // Karma configuration
// Generated on Thu Apr 14 2016 14:50:35 GMT+0200 (Central Europe Summer Time)

module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
    basePath: '',


    // frameworks to use
    // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],


    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
      'js/*.js'
    ],


    // list of files to exclude
    exclude: [
    ],


    // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
    // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
    preprocessors: {
    },


    // test results reporter to use
    // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
    // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
    reporters: ['progress'],


    // web server port
    port: 9876,


    // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
    colors: true,


    // level of logging
    // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: true,


    // start these browsers
    // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
    browsers: ['Chrome'],


    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
    singleRun: false,

    // Concurrency level
    // how many browser should be started simultaneous
    concurrency: Infinity
  })
}
```

When I start karma (`karma start karma.conf.js`) a new chrome tab opened up, with the port, specified in the config file. The test ran, everything worked as expected. However, when I changed something in the `.test.js` file, Karma didn't autorun. Actually, no changes were made. I had to restart Karma in CMD and ran again in order to see the new results.

However, if I open a new CMD and execute `karma run` the test get updated. So, the part that watches for changes doesn't work, obviously.

So, I have no idea what I'm missing here, but auto-watch function of Karma is not working anymore. Any suggestions where I should start?

Comment: Were you ever able to resolve this? If so please post your answer.

Answer (score 3):

I Just finally found the fix after months of looking.

I'm sure there are other ways to disable cache in chrome.  But this worked for me right away.

Once you type `karma start`, and chrome launches, enable dev tools, and on the network tab, check `disable cache`